# Pygame low frame rate but waiting on input instantly

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface, pygame-tick

I want to create simple game in python with pygame. There are some buttons, but it doesnt respond sometimes. I want to have low frame rate because its simple game but also i want to have buttons waiting on click like always. is it posible?

Its like if i dont click in that 60/1000 miliseconds its not working, am I right? If I am then is there other posibility to run game at 60 fps and waiting for input like always?

using this to catch click:

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if pos[0] > 500 and pos[0] < 600 and pos[1] > 620 and pos[1] < 680:
                button_hod_clicked = True
```

using this in main loop:

```
clock.tick(FPS)
```

structure:

```
def check_buttons(pos):

    button_hod_clicked = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if pos[0] > 500 and pos[0] < 600 and pos[1] > 620 and pos[1] < 680:
                button_hod_clicked = True

    return button_hod_clicked



def main():
   run = True
   striedanie = True
   while run:
      clock.tick(FPS)
      pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      button_hod_clicked = check_buttons(pos)
      if button_hod_clicked:
          if striedanie == True:
              player1_position, kolko_hodil = player_movement(player1_position)
              striedanie = False
            else:
              player2_position, kolko_hodil = player_movement(player2_position)
              striedanie = True
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: How often do you call `pygame.event.get()` in the application loop?

Comment: How low is your frame rate?

Comment: 60, but I also tried 120 there is improvement but really low. At 1000 FPS it's fine but it's a lot FPS

Comment: please provide a proper [mre], for example we don't know what `pos` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the mouse position every frame, just get the mouse position if the event handler detects `MOUSEBUTTONUP` and call the `check_buttons` function.

```py
def check_buttons(pos):
    return pos[0] > 500 and pos[0] < 600 and pos[1] > 620 and pos[1] < 680

button_hod_clicked = False
def main():
    global button_hod_clicked
    ...
    ...
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            button_hod_clicked = check_buttons(pos)

    if button_hod_clicked:
        ...
```

Let me know if this works.

Note: `time.sleep` pauses the whole program, so it freezes the window.

Comment: yeah, thanks man. its working. I had to check for MOUSEBUTTONDOWN in main loop and in the function "check_buttons" only if its in that position